# How to "default" a column in a SELECT query

Tags: sql, select, db2, query-optimization

Say I have a database table T with 4 fields, A, B, C, and D.  A, B, and C are the primary key.  For any combination of [A, B], there is always a row where `C == spaces`.  There may or may not be other rows where `C != spaces`.  I have a query that gets all rows where `[A, B] == [in_a, in_b]`, and also where `C == in_c` if such a row exists, or `C == spaces` if the in_c row doesn't exist.  So, if there is a row that matches the particular C value, I want that one, otherwise I want the spaces one.  It is very important that if there is a matching C row, that I not be returned the spaces one along with it.

I have a working query, but its not very fast.  This is executing on DB2 for z/OS.  I have full control over these tables, so I can define new indicies if needed.  The only index on the table right now is `[A, B, C]`, the primary key.  This SQL is kinda messy, and I feel theres a better way to accomplish this task.  What can I do to make this query faster?

The query I have now is:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D FROM T
WHERE A = :IN_A AND B > :IN_B AND
       (C = :IN_C 
        OR (NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT B FROM T WHERE 
              A = :IN_A AND B > :IN_B AND C = :IN_C)) 
            AND C = " ");
```

Comment: Whoops, had a = instead of a > in the SQL.  This query always returns multiple rows, hence the B > :IN_B part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work on DB2 LUW, not sure if the order by clause works on DB2 Z:

```
select 
   a, b, c, d 
  from t 
 where a = :IN_A 
   and b = :IN_B 
   and c in (:IN_C,'  ') 
order by 
   case c when '  ' then 2 else 1 end 
fetch first 1 row only
```

Make sure that the '  ' value matches the actual value of the column.

Good luck,

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat emptor*, as I am not familiar with DB2 SQL...

You could try using an ORDER BY clause to sort the matching rows such that a row with c = spaces is last in the sorted set, then retrieve just the first row of the set. Something like:

```
select first
    A, B, C, D
  from T
  where A = :IN_A
    and B = :IN_B
  order by C desc;
```

This assumes that the FIRST and ORDER BY DESC clauses do what I expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

Why not start up the index advisor and reads its advices? (or is this only on DB2 for i/OS?)

We use the advisor for our very big production environment and it gives great advices. But having that said, it's always good to start with a good statement.